Extension "Documents" v.1.25 Network error + error in civicase
I'm very new to civicrm and have the latest version 5.76.2 running on a wordpress basis, also with the latest version. Now I wanted to test the "Documents" extension, so I installed it, but an error appears every time I open the "Documents" tab in a contact. The error message is:
"Network error - Could not reach the server. Please refresh the page in the browser you are using and try again."
Now I've also noticed that I can no longer edit cases in civicase, because the error message appears: "Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Documents/Page/CaseDocuments.tpl'"
I found this thread (Documents tab Network error) and a patch inside, but the latest version is even newer, so is there another patch for the Documents extension or how can I solve both problems manually?

You should be able to temporarily fix it by commenting out this line in civicrm.settings.php: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4db073be8b41bf3cea765f34fa35ea4d8d58b0db/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template#L280, i.e. change
define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH', $civicrm_root . '/packages/smarty4/vendor/autoload.php');
to
// define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH', $civicrm_root . '/packages/smarty4/vendor/autoload.php');
The documents extension looks like it's up to date so not sure offhand what a more permanent fix is.

if you have access to the server with command line, run civix upgrade inside the /ext/documents folder. Some extensions are not yet compatible with recent versions of CiviCRM involving Smarty v4 and this quick trick has proven to fix this issue.
If not yet done and opened on the extension's repository, you can also open an issue and if you have any dev skills you could also offer a commit to fix this issue.
:-)
